# Piping file to a command that doesn't implement piping

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, pipe

```
$ cat foo
foo
bar
```

Now if I do:

```
$ some_program foo
```

It's working.

But if I try:

```
$ cat foo | some_program
```

It's not working.

I'm looking for a clean way to pipe input to `some_program` *without* having to use messy temporary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piping will put `cat foo`'s stdout to `some_program`'s stdin. In this case `some_program` is expecting an argument, not stdin, so you'll want to store `cat foo`'s result into a variable and then call `some_program $variable`.

I'm not too sure on bash scripting, but try this?

```
bar=`cat foo`
some_program $bar
```

Actually, maybe this will work...

```
some_program `cat foo`
```

Comment: You're the best!

Comment: ms123: Please edit your question if you were looking command line argumets from file instead of filename. Based on your current question this is different thing

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can use process substitution

```
$ some_program <(cat foo)
```

You can add as much parameters as you like this way as long you know that these parameters will be file names that will be read only. You can't read and write at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the way @Bob proposed, there is another, more flexible method: `xargs`:

You could use

```
cat foo | xargs some_program
```

which is basically equivalent of

```
some_program `cat foo`
```

If the program is expecting only one argument at a time, you can do

```
cat foo | xargs -n 1 some_program
```

And `some_program` would be called once for each input line.

There are many other options to `xargs`, like careful handling of "bad" filenames (with spaces and other special characters), limiting the number of simultaneously running processes etc., which could be found in man-page.